# finite measure and cauchy in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've been trying to prove that If $(f_{n})_{n}$ is cauchy in measure, i.e $\mu(|f_{n}-f_{m}|\geq\delta)<\epsilon$ for $n,m $ relatively big then it converges to a measurable function in measure. Now, if $\mu(\Omega)$ is finite then it is enough to prove that if $(f_{n})_{n}$(which converges cauchy in measure) converges a.e to a measurable function, because in a space of finite measure, convergence almost everywhere implies convergence in measure. This might be a really basic question, but I havent been able to prove it.

Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks guys <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea may not work. Consider the probability measure, i.e. $\mu(\Omega)=1$. Define an independent sequence $\{X_n\}$ by
$$X_n=\left\{
\begin{array}
1 1 &\text{with probability } n^{-1},\\
0 &\text{with probability }1-n^{-1}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
You can check that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability, i.e. in measure but $\{X_n\}$ does not converge almost surely.

For the proof of your problem, see [Cauchy in measure implies convergent in measure.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789816/cauchy-in-measure-implies-convergent-in-measure)

Comment: But then, whats the use for a finite measure in my problem? o:

Comment: @asd123 I think the assumption of finite measure is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but then, whats the freakin difference between cauchy in measure and convergence in measure D: I suppose convergence in measure is stronger but no entirely sure haha, i mean the practical difference D:

Comment: @asd123 As far as I know, they’re equivalent. Maybe my last statement is not true in some cases. After all, I’m not very sure about it. My understanding is that the notation of “Cauchy in measure” is a convenience for usage. For example, there are cases where the proof of “Cauchy in measure” is easier than the direct proof of “convergence in measure”.